# How do I union multiple WITH clause in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server

For example I have 2 or more `WITH` clause statements something like the codes attached below as an example.

How do I union multiple `WITH` clause statements together? Please advice thanks a lot.

SQL Server:

```
-- WITH clause 1
WITH Sales_CTE (SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, SalesYear)
AS
(
    SELECT SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, YEAR(OrderDate) AS SalesYear
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    WHERE SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT SalesPersonID, COUNT(SalesOrderID) AS TotalSales, SalesYear
FROM Sales_CTE
GROUP BY SalesYear, SalesPersonID

-- WITH clause 2
WITH Sales_CTE (SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, SalesYear)
AS
(
    SELECT SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, YEAR(OrderDate) AS SalesYear
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    WHERE SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT SalesPersonID, COUNT(SalesOrderID) AS TotalSales, SalesYear
FROM Sales_CTE
GROUP BY SalesYear, SalesPersonID

-- WITH clause 3
WITH Sales_CTE (SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, SalesYear)
AS
(
    SELECT SalesPersonID, SalesOrderID, YEAR(OrderDate) AS SalesYear
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    WHERE SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT SalesPersonID, COUNT(SalesOrderID) AS TotalSales, SalesYear
FROM Sales_CTE
GROUP BY SalesYear, SalesPersonID
```

Comment: Is this really SQL Server? It does not have `NATURAL JOIN`. And what's the different between `WITH` clause 1 & 2?

Comment: All three CTE's (Common Table Expression) seems to select exactly the same columns from exactly the same table for exactly the same criteria....

Answer (score 2):

Separate them by just `,` and remove `WITH`

```
WITH
  sum_sales1 AS 
  (
      --Code here
  ) 
  ,sum_sales2 AS 
  (
       --Code here 
  )

 SELECT * FROM sum_sales1
 UNION
 SELECT * FROM sum_sales2
```